# how to access the resource bundle properties file directly with filename.property()

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I found a strange way to access the resource bundle properties. Here they are:

1. Project View:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhLGd.png)
2. Messages.properites:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ov2.png)
3. Get property: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luVcW.png)

Can someone tell me how to do it? Should I import other third packages or do some operations on resource bundles.

Comment: **Don't post images of text!** Post the text itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `found the strange way`? Does your IDE support it? What is your IDE? I know similar feature from [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nMessages.html) but that works because you have to describe property file with interface and GWT will generate code implementing that interface.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post, I thought images would show directly like markdown,  the IDE i used is intej IDEA, I don't know wheter IDEA support it or not. In my opinion there should have some build step to make the Resource Bundle to classes.  but i don't know it.

Comment: I have found the build step,  there is a localizer plugins: org.jvnet.localizer:maven-localizer-plugin.

Comment: @杨功勇 If you found solution, feel free to answer your question and later accept it, so future visitors may easily find the solution.